# Missing search result on SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, search

I was trying to find [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111380/i-copied-my-password-to-the-clipboard-can-you-delete-it/) using the search bar in the Android app. Searching for "clip board" or "clip-board" returned nothing, and "clipboard" only returned a single irrelevant result.

When using the full site however, "clipboard" turns up many results not shown in the app, including the question I was looking for.

Is this a bug? An optimization limitation? It would be nice if their behavior was the same. This isn't the first time I was unable to find something in the app, but found it immediately on the full site.

"Proof":

> [image: Proof]

Comment: The android app itself is inferior. If you want features, use the website or the iOS app. Otherwise, expect tons of bugs or weird problems in the android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

> [image: clipboard]

Please check that you selected site where you want to search as active.

Seems that "Newest" sort mode filter some questions. I don't know why. Try to change it and see the result.

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: @Carcigenicate answer updated.

Comment: Ahh! That's weird. I expected "Newest" to just define the sorting.

Comment: @Carcigenicate me too. But in my case "Active" is default sorting, thus I couldn't saw this weird behavior.