# Connection problems / time-outs on Android App

Tags: support, android-app

While I understand no new development is being done on the Stack Exchange Android app, I still find it useful for keeping an eye on questions & answers and doing some moderation tasks. (The push notifications help improve my response times)

Starting early this morning, I noticed it's become extremely slow when loading the feed, questions, or posting comments. To the point where it will often time out and need to be retried several times before it succeeds.

I'm not observing similar delays when accessing the mobile site, so I don't think it's an issue with my device, my connection, or the Stack Exchange servers as a whole.

Any indications of what could be causing this slowdown?

I'm using version 1.0.95 of the app on a Google Pixel 2 running Android version 9

Comment: Likely API issue, the API is what being used to "energize" the app, while the site takes its data directly from database. Think it happens quite often, though not for so long, always to get sorted out eventually.

Comment: It's been derpy for a few days now. The profile screen is no longer showing recent activity for me, and ya, stuff is randomly taking an abnormal time to load (or not loading at all). Not sure if this is related, but my filter search (not related to the app) keeps showing "no results", even though I know there are results available. That's off and on though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Likely API, but only Android app specific API, cause iOS app works normal (in such case) for me. Worth noting that I use iOS app via home WiFi, but Android app via mobile internet (more stricted, not only for speed, but also amount of blocked content by cellphone operator than my home provider does) I noticed extremly long delays on post/comment loading for Android app a couple weeks ago. I still get notifications via app, but most of time it's imposible to open comment source in app, so I need to open web version (no matter mobile or full) of SE to see the comment and answer it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate are you still talking about that [search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295684/339911)? :)

Comment: @älёxölüt No, not that one. I did post about it though a few months ago